# How to redirect all pages to one page on the same server through htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect all pages to one page on the same server.
In other words I need to redirect:

`www.example.com` (which can be whatever, including for example `www.example.com/something`)

to

`www.example.com/maintenance`

I've tried multiple versions of this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !SOME_COOKIE=TRUE; [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/maintenance [L,NC]
```

but i end up with error message in the browser "Too many redirects" or not everything is redirecting...
Any help would be greatly appropriated.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I did and still the same thing. It's getting redirected silly number of times. I'm now looking at some trace logs (LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/maintenance [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect any URLs that are `example.com/anything` to `https://www.example.com/maintenance`.

This is achieved using 301 Redirection. ***While testing this make sure you change it to*** `R=302` ***as that is a temporary redirect***. Once happy, chance it back to `R=301`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. (Or use a private browser).